# How can Orika map objects without instantiating a new destination object

Tags: java, dto, orika

I need to replace Dozer mappings by Orika and I want to know if it's possible to do this Dozer stuff `mapper.map(obj1, obj2)` in Orika? I have seen so far that for destination you can only specify the class type and not an object, so I am assuming that a new instance will get created each time. But in this case I need to only update a previously found entity object with some fields of the DTO. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to both map source object `A` to a target class `B` - then Orika will instantiate `B` by itself - or to an already created instance of `B`.

```
// Let Orika create instance of B
A source = new A();
BoundMapperFacade<A, B> mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(A.class, B.class);
B target = mapper.map(source);

// Create instance of B yourself and let Orika fill it
A source = new A();
B target = new B();
BoundMapperFacade<A, B> mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(A.class, B.class);
mapper.map(source, target);
```

In the second case you can set up the `target` instance yourself in some way - Orika will only map the properties from `A` to `B` that you defined in the `ClassMap`.

Comment: What to do, to get this behaviour occur to internal Object.

Comment: @ShineedBasheer - Orika will instantiate all internal objects automatically or it will use the existing ones if they are there.

Comment: But i tested the same to map persistence object with value object. Actually i want to merge these object. By preserving persistencr related state on object.  Object is complex in sence it contain List of internal object and each internal obect has recursive structure. Orika maps outter object as you said. But for internal objects it is creating new objects

Comment: @ShineedBasheer - I suggest you create a new question, giving code samples of your issue (a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to help just via comments.

Comment: Created a new Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275861/will-orika-map-complex-object-having-recursive-structure